# mobx observe component not trigg componentDidMount method

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

This is my component below contains two button(decrement, increment) and I want decrement button to be hidden when a property`(@observable number)` in AppState(Mobx) value equals to 10 and when number changes mobx rerender component it works fine.

I put a debugger inside componentDidMount,

```
   @observer
class Questions extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.appState=this.props.appState
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    debugger
      if(this.appState.num==10){
        document.getElementById("btnDecrement").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("btnDecrement").style.visibility = "block";
      }
    }
    ...
    render(){

        return(
          <div>
          ...
            <button id="btnDecrement" onClick={()=>{this.appState.decrementNumber()}} type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-lg">
              Decrement
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={()=>{this.incrementNumber()}} className="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                   Increment;
                </button>
          </div>

        )
    }
}
    }
```

it stops there at only after page load that makes sense but I need to make this check each time number edited.

Edited: it makes sense mobx works this way, componentDidMount only triggers once it mounted. But then how can I handle my logic here in "efficient way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

componentDidMount is only called once in the program you described. (after the component is mounted)

Dont try to hide/show the button with css properties.
Instead write in your render method in the jsx

```
render() {
  return (
    ...
    { this.appState.num === 10 ?
      (<button 
         type="button" 
         onClick={()=>{this.incrementNumber()}} 
         className="btn btn-default btn-lg"
       >
         Increment;
       </button>)
      : null
    }
  );
}
```

So what you are doing here, you are using a ternary operator to decide wether to let react render the button or not (then it returns null)

This way your increment button gets autmatically hidden when number === 10